# What's the practice for short-forming or nicknaming words called?

Tags: nicknames

Is there any term for the habit of playing around with words, or even names, and nickname them? Like 'No' becoming 'nopes', 'whatever' becoming 'tevs', milky-wilky etc. This happens a lot with cricket teams, who keep nicknaming people - Wilkinson becomes Willy or Wilks, Hogg becomes Hoggy (though it's longer).

Comment: For people, "nicknaming" would be the word I would use.

Answer (score 1):

'Nicknaming' specifically for names.

Other words you can use: 'abbreviation' or 'to abbreviate' and 'dimimutive'

> **di·min·u·tive** (adjective) /diˈminyətiv/
>
> Extremely or unusually small
>   - a diminutive figure dressed in black
>
> (of a word, name, or suffix) Implying smallness, either actual or
>   imputed in token of   affection, scorn, etc., (e.g., teeny, -let,
>   -kins)